# Stratos waiting forever

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

Following the guide for WSO2 Private PaaS, when running `./boot.sh`, after the

> Starting WSO2 Private PaaS server as ubuntu user...

There would be nothing going on.

Stratos version: Apache Stratos v4.0.0-wso2v1

In private-paas `/install/apache-stratos-default/repository/logs` directory:
the `wso2carbon.log` giving repeat message as:

```
[2015-05-06 10:27:38,573]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:
[2015-05-06 10:27:38,574]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.identity.provider-4.2.1
[2015-05-06 10:28:38,574]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:
```

What does this mean? Any suggestions?

Comment: If the issue is not resolved you can also ask from the WSO2 dev mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Stratos is based on WSO2 Carbon which itself is an OSGI based framework. From the WARN messages it seems to be waiting for the identity provider OSGI bundle to be loaded. Check if the stated Jar file is available in `<STRATOS_HOME>/repository/components/plugin` path during server start. If there is one, check if its md5sum is the same as the one that is distributed with Private PaaS. There is a possibility that the jar file is corrupted and could not be loaded as a bundle.

Comment: thanks. with the hint, I downloaded an offical binary release version, and passed .